# How to use matshow command to generate heat map?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have (320,100) matrix. I want to plot its heat map. Rows of the matrix should be along x axis and columns should be along y axis. I am using matshow function for this.Does matshow function gives rows along x-axis or columns? Beside it is labeling x-axis from 0 to 100 and y-axis from 0 to 300. Why it is doing so? why it is not picking the values of the matrix?

```
[[-0.2706643  -0.25426278 -0.06284858 ..., -0.06432685  0.03350727
  -0.09772336]
 ..., 

 [-0.2630468  -0.2508091  -0.16554087 ..., -0.3019954   0.11554097
  -0.13261844]]
```

Comment: I do not understand "why it is not picking the values of the matrix?" The values of a matrix are shown as colors in the heatmap. They are unrelated to the x any y axis. What would you like to have on the x and y axis?

Answer (score 3):

Here is how an array is indexed and how the resulting `imshow` or `matshow` plot looks like. The array here is of shape (7,5), so you have 7 rows and 5 columns. Columns are `x`, and rows are `y`.

[image]

Here is the difference between `imshow` and `matshow`, `imshow`has the x ticklabels on the bottom of the graph.

[image]

You may transpose an array to have the columns turned into rows and vice versa. If `A` is your array and you have `import`ed `numpy as np`, do

```
A = np.array(A).T
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a nice explanation.

Comment: If this answers your question, consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it. I realize you have never accepted an answer to any of your questions, so you may want to read about it. If on the other hand, there are still open issues, you may edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume your Matrix is called "my_matrix".
To check number of rows,

```
print len(my_matrix)
```

To check correct number of columns,
`print len(my_matrix[0])`.

If it is incorrect, transform your matrix to a numpy array (I always do this per default) with numpy_array = numpy.array(my_matrix).
Then perform a matrix reshape with numpy_array.reshape(rows, columns)

You can plot this matrix 3-dimensionally with matplotlib:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.set_aspect('equal')
X = np.arange(xstart, xend, 1)
Y = np.arange(ystart, yend, 1)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)

surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, matrix_to_plot , rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.hot, linewidth=0, antialiased=True)

ax.zaxis.set_major_locator(LinearLocator(5))
ax.zaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.02f'))
ax.set_xlim([xstart, xend])
ax.set_ylim([ystart, yend])
ax.set_xlabel("X")
ax.set_ylabel("Y")

fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining but i have to plot it in two dimension with matshow function. But the rows of the matrix should be along x-axis and columns should be along y-axis

Comment: Moreover i also want to that this function assigns the values along lower x axis not at the top of the figure