# Understanding pcolor plots

Tags: matplotlib

I'm trying to find something that helps me get an understanding of what a pcolor (Pseudocolor) plot is and how it functions. I have had it set as an example in a course I'm doing but it has little explanation as to it's use or how it functions on data.

I've tried searching and I have found https://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pcolor.html

But that hasn't helped any further with my understanding of exactly how it functions. Does anyone know of a good tutorial or explanation they could point me to so I could read through to get a handle on what this plot actually is.

Comment: Are you looking for an answer how `plt.pcolor` works internally or what it is used for/ what kind of information such a plot contains?

Comment: The later. I understand it is utilised for comparing two variables (typically related to each other), but I don't understand what it is showing me with it's representation of those data points. Such as how it is plotted based on the variable values and why particular colors are used. I hope that is clearer about what I am after.

Comment: Think of a two-dimensional space, two coordinates `x` and `y`. Now every point in this space can have an additional property that can be described by a number, say a temperature or a heigth (if you're looking at a map). This additional scalar property is encoded by the color. If the additional property would be a vector (e.g. magnetic field in 2d space) then you would use a quiverplot.

Comment: maybe this will give more context to my question. One of the examples they have demonstrating pcolor is done against the array np.array([[1, 0, -1], [2, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1]]). There is a dark blue box (cmap='Blues') on the left middle of the grid and a white box in the bottom right. I can't figure out the relationship to the array and what I'm seeing.

Comment: Print the array and see for yourself that there's the largest value in the array. Maybe plot a colorbar as well: 
`a = np.array([[1, 0, -1],
              [2, 0, 1],
              [1, 1, 1]])`
`p = plt.pcolor(a, cmap='Blues')`
`plt.colorbar(p)`

Comment: I have printed the array. That's how I knew the dark blue box is on the left middle of the grid. I just don't understand why. Even with the colorbar. I can't see the relation to the array and the way the graph looks. It's why I was hoping to find something that explains the plotting that is done in a pcolor plot so I can understand what makes the colors display the way they are. But I haven't had any luck finding such an explanation walking me through how a pcolor plot is performed if it was to be done manually unfortunately.

Comment: Ok I think I've figure it out. It's about layering them values into a matrix for what it's displaying. I found a site that explained it but didn't mention it as a Pseudocolor plot. https://processing.org/tutorials/2darray/

Comment: Every entry of the 2d array is interpreted as a pixel. Then you just plot these pixels. Notice that the coordinate system might not be as you expect: When I plotted the above example with the array `a`, the last line `[1, 1, 1]` was on top. Now I hope you see the correlation between the array and the plot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`pcolor`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.pcolor) plots the contents of an `n x m` array on a grid of `(n+1) x (m+1)`, such that the `j`th value in the array in one dimension is shown in the plot between the `j`th and `(j+1)`th grid value, colored according to a colormap.

[image]

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(1) 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

NumX, NumY = 5,7
x = np.linspace(-2,3, num=NumX+1)
y = np.linspace(-4,3, num=NumY+1)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
Data = np.random.randint(1,9,size=(NumY,NumX))

fig, ax  = plt.subplots(figsize=(4,4))
ax.set_title("pcolor")

im = ax.pcolor(X,Y,Data)

for i in range(Data.shape[0]):
    for j in range(Data.shape[1]):
        ax.text(X[i,j],Y[i,j], Data[i,j], color="w", size=15)

plt.colorbar(im)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Note that `pcolor` behaves slightly different than `imshow` or `matshow`, as seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43039242/how-to-use-matshow-command-to-generate-heat-map).